# Is the onEdit function working on the New Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I tried the following function on both the new and the old google sheets, but it only works on the latter:

```
function onEdit() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var cell = s.getActiveCell();
  var val = cell.getValue();  
  var icol = cell.getColumn();
  if (icol == 8){
    if (val == "Em contacto"){
      var roar = cell.getRow();
      var tcell = s.getRange(roar,14);
      var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-3", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
      tcell.setValue(date);
    };
  };
}
```

It simply adds a timestamp to column N whenever a cell in column H is edited with the string "Em contacto".

Is there a different way of getting this done without using an old sheet?

Answer (score 0):

There are some known issues with some of the Spreadsheet service methods

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/migration/sheets#issues_with_individual_methods

In your specific case, the call s.getActiveCell() will return an incorrect range (in my testing it is always row = 1, column = 1).

It's a shame, and a problem that means I can't upgrade some of my sheets yet :-(

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is indeed a specific known issue for the onEdit trigger:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/migration/sheets#onedit_triggers